# Constructing a great circle in plan and front view given two points on the surface of a sphere.

Tags: geometry

Since I've seen similar questions I guess this goes in here lacking better options.

Right, my problem is the following. I've been given 2 points P and Q on the surface of a sphere and I'm to construct the shortest distance between them in plan and front view of the sphere. So I'm going to end up with some sort of ellipse since the shortest path is a great circle.

Which also means that I got 3 points which define my plane in which the circle lies.

What I cannot figure out for the life of me is how to draw this using pen, straightedge and compass. I really could use a step by step walk through.

Not wanted are equations, they are easily obtained from the internet.

Comment: No part of a proper ellipse is circular, so you can’t draw this with a compass. You can approximate it though, e.g., [this way](http://jep-s.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-draw-ellipse-by-four-center.html).

Comment: The issue is not the approximation of the final ellipse. I'm failing at constructing the points.